# How to create a side swiping photo gallery in Swift/iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I am looking to create a side swiping photo gallery. There are many tutorials that show how to make one with a tableview, but I'd like to make a gallery that starts off with an image and allows you to swipe left or right to browse. Does anyone know of a github extension or tutorial, or have any knowledge to help point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Something like this:
[image: Some]

Comment: Use UICollectionView with paging enabled

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to have the option of not having a collection view / simply have left and right swipe navigation

Comment: UIPageViewController.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could do this on a regular viewController... You could probably find some animations for this, but I guess this is a step in the right direction:

First, define an imageView and the images to go inside:

```
// Connect a UIImageView to the outlet below
@IBOutlet weak var swipeImageView: UIImageView!
// Type in the names of your images below
let imageNames = ["","","","",""]
```

Then, in the viewDidLoad, set up gestureRecognizers for the directions:

```
    var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    var swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
```

After that, you can set up the function that was called to manage the image switches.

```
 var currentImage = 0
 func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {


        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
            if currentImage == imageNames.count - 1 {
                currentImage = 0

            }else{
                currentImage += 1
            }
            swipeImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageNames[currentImage])

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
            if currentImage == 0 {
                currentImage = imageNames.count - 1
            }else{
                currentImage -= 1
            }
            swipeImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageNames[currentImage])
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Full viewController code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {



    // Connect a UIImageView to the outlet below
    @IBOutlet weak var swipeImageView: UIImageView!
    // Type in the names of your images below
    let imageNames = ["","","","",""]



    var currentImage = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        var swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {


            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
                if currentImage == imageNames.count - 1 {
                    currentImage = 0

                }else{
                    currentImage += 1
                }
                swipeImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageNames[currentImage])

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
                if currentImage == 0 {
                    currentImage = imageNames.count - 1
                }else{
                    currentImage -= 1
                }
                swipeImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageNames[currentImage])
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi. It's seem your above code does not help show percent swipe as show other image before it swipe dont (to left/right), sorry for my bad english

Comment: @famfamfam You're right, this is unideal in terms of the animations. This is important to note for anyone implementing this: the images will flash on top of each other without animations. If someone gets the code to work to show the progress of the swipes like in the question, it would surely beat my answer.

Comment: This is terrific! Just remember to set the view you are swiping to have myImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true