# View is not detecting Gesture Recognizer for swipe image gallery

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer

I would like to have a `SwipeImageGallery` inside my `CustomShareExtensionViewController` but right now it is not detecting the `gestures`  and I don't know why.

**Images:**

```
let images: [UIImage] = [
            UIImage(named: "avocadoImage")!,        // 0
            UIImage(named: "beerImage")!,           // 1
            UIImage(named: "bikeImage")!,           // 2
            UIImage(named: "christmasImage")!,      // 3
            UIImage(named: "dressImage")!,          // 4
            UIImage(named: "giftImage")!,           // 5
            UIImage(named: "rollerImage")!,         // 6
            UIImage(named: "shirtImage")!,          // 7
            UIImage(named: "shoeImage")!,           // 8
            UIImage(named: "travelImage")!,         // 9
            UIImage(named: "iconRoundedImage")!,
]
```

**ViewDidLoad:**

```
let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToSwipeGesture))
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToSwipeGesture))
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
```

**respondToGesture**:

```
@objc func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left:
            if currentImage == images.count - 1 {
                currentImage = 0

            }else{
                currentImage += 1
            }
            swipeImageView.image = images[currentImage]

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right:
            if currentImage == 0 {
                currentImage = images.count - 1
            }else{
                currentImage -= 1
            }
            swipeImageView.image = images[currentImage]
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I got this `code` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529775/how-to-create-a-side-swiping-photo-gallery-in-swift-ios/38530797) SO-post. Am I doing anything wrong? I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Do you have isUserInteractionEnabled for swipeImageView ?

Comment: @HalR not before, but I changed it and that didn't solve the issue. Another thing is that there is no image being shown at the beginning at all.

Answer (score 0):

Tap on the image view then go to the **Attributes inspector** and make sure that you've enabled **User Interaction Enabled**

[image]